# Jquery if it does not work as expected whit $.post

Tags: jquery, if-statement, .post

I have a php file which returns error if a check fails captcha.

and I have this Jquery code to connect using php post to that.

```
$.post(url,{recaptcha_challenge_field: campo1, recaptcha_response_field: campo2 , tipo: pollo},function(respuesta){
if(respuesta == "error")
{
    console.log("enter if");
}
else{
    console.log("enter else");
}       });
```

but apparently when error enters the "if" goes directly to the "else".
if the answer is wrong always enters the "else"

Comment: Can you log `respuesta` for us ?

Comment: "respuesta" would have to be "error" if check failed or "true" if the comparison was successful

Comment: @RonalVasquez Right, but that's obviously not what is happening. if you're getting to the else incorrectly, `respuesta` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: obviously "response" is returning me "Error" instead of "error" you're getting into me several blanks and not as pull them off

Comment: @Ronal, please consider posting your last comment as an answer (I would suggest you omit `obviously` and the part about blanks) so your question is properly resolved.